# Searching by Entity Name and Last Modified Date

Tags: ravendb

I have a number of commands stored in RavenDb and they all implement ICommand.  I want to be able to search on the metadata of last modified and Raven-Entity-Name. I am currently doing a multi map on each command as below:

```
public class CommandAuditSearch_Index : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<CommandAuditSearch_Index.Results>
    {
        public class Results
        {
            public string CommandType { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        }

        public CommandAuditSearch_Index()
        {
            AddMap<NewEmployeeStartCommand>(employees => employees.Select(x => new
            {
                CommandType = MetadataFor(x).Value<string>("Raven-Entity-Name"),
                LastModified = MetadataFor(x).Value<DateTime>("Last-Modified")
            }));

            AddMap<EmployeeLeaverCommand>(employees => employees.Select(x => new
            {
                CommandType = MetadataFor(x).Value<string>("Raven-Entity-Name"),
                LastModified = MetadataFor(x).Value<DateTime>("Last-Modified")
            }));

            Index(results => results.CommandType, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        }
    }
```

I query this as follows:

```
session.Query<CommandAuditSearch_Index.Results, CommandAuditSearch_Index>()
                              .Where(x => x.CommandType == commandType && x.LastModified >= DateTime.Today).OfType<ICommand>().ToList();
```

I know there is an index already built into Raven to get the Tag (entity name) and last modified date but I cant seem to figure out how to get the results as my index above gives me.

can anyone point me in the right direction of a static index where I don't have to have the multi maps as above for each command I have to query that gives me the results as a list of ICommands?

Thanks

Paddy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of points:

- You don't need to mark a field as analyzed unless you are going to be doing fulltext searching with the `Search` query method.  If you are just using `Where`, there is no advantage to analyzing the index term.
- If you are looking for metadata values in your results, you simply need to get them from the metadata instead of the document data using `GetMetadataFor`.  [Reference here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/document-metadata).
- As you said, there's already an index for what you need.  The easiest way to query it is using the `LuceneQuery` API.

  ```
  var tag = documentStore.Conventions.GetTypeTagName(theCommand.GetType());

  var results = session.Advanced
                       .LuceneQuery<ICommand, RavenDocumentsByEntityName>()
                       .WhereEquals("Tag", tag)
                       .AndAlso()
                       .WhereGreaterThanOrEqual("LastModified", DateTime.Today
                                                            .ToUniversalTime())
                       .ToList();

  foreach (var result in results)
  {
      var md = session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(result);
      var entityName = md.Value<string>("Raven-Entity-Name");
      var lastModified = md.Value<DateTime>("Last-Modified");

      // you can see all the metadata if you like
      Debug.WriteLine(md.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Matt.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  I always find your answers detailed and well explained.