# Creating a completely dynamic query with RavenDB using LuceneQuery

Tags: c#, ravendb, lucene.net

I want one method that can query my entire RavenDB database.

My method signature looks like this:

```
public static DataTable GetData(string className, int amount, string orderByProperty, string filterByProperty, string filterByOperator, string filterCompare)
```

I figured I can accomplish all of the above with a dynamic LuceneQuery.

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<dynamic>();
```

The problem is: Since I'm using `dynamic` in the type given, how do I ensure that the query only includes the types matching the **className**?

I'm looking for something like `.WhereType(className)` or `.Where("type: " + className)`.

**Solution**

This returns the results of the correct type:

```
var type = Type.GetType("Business.Data.DTO." + className);

var tagName = RavenDb.GetTypeTagName(type);
using (var session = RavenDb.OpenSession())
{
    var result = session.Advanced
                        .LuceneQuery<object, RavenDocumentsByEntityName>()
                        .WhereEquals("Tag", tagName)
                        .ToList();
}
```

Note, it is not possible to add additional "WhereEquals" or other filters to this. This is because nothing specific to that document type is included in the "RavenDocumentByEntityName" index.

This means that this solution cannot be used for what I wanted to accomplish.

**What I ended up doing**

Although it doesn't fulfill my requirement completely, this is what I ended up doing:

```
public static List<T> GetData<T>(DataQuery query)
{
    using (var session = RavenDb.OpenSession())
    {
        var result = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.FilterByProperty))
        {
            if (query.FilterByOperator == "=")
            {
                result = result.WhereEquals(query.FilterByProperty, query.FilterCompare);
            }
            else if (query.FilterByOperator == "StartsWith")
            {
                result = result.WhereStartsWith(query.FilterByProperty, query.FilterCompare);
            }
            else if (query.FilterByOperator == "EndsWith")
            {
                result = result.WhereEndsWith(query.FilterByProperty, query.FilterCompare);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.OrderByProperty))
        {
            if (query.Descending)
            {
                result = result.OrderBy(query.OrderByProperty);
            }
            else
            {
                result = result.OrderByDescending(query.OrderByProperty);
            }
        }

        result = result.Skip(query.Skip).Take(query.Amount);

        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Although this is most certainly an anti-pattern, it's a neat way to just look at some data, if that's what you want. It's called very easily like this:

```
DataQuery query = new DataQuery
{
    Amount = int.Parse(txtAmount.Text),
    Skip = 0,
    FilterByProperty = ddlFilterBy.SelectedValue,
    FilterByOperator = ddlOperator.SelectedValue,
    FilterCompare = txtCompare.Text,
    OrderByProperty = ddlOrderBy.SelectedValue,
    Descending = chkDescending.Checked
};

grdData.DataSource = DataService.GetData<Server>(query);
grdData.DataBind();
```

"Server" is one of the classes/document types I'm working with, so the downside, where it isn't **completely** dynamic, is that I would have to define a call like that for each type.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you don't go down this road.  You are essentially attempting to hide the RavenDB Session object, which is very powerful and intended to be used directly.

Just looking at the signature of the method you want to create, the parameters are all very restrictive and make a lot of assumptions that might not be true for the data you're working on.  And the return type - why would you return a `DataTable`?  Maybe return an `object` or a `dynamic`, but nothing in Raven is structured in tables, so `DataTable` is a bad idea.

To answer the specific question, the type name comes from the `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata, which you would need to build an index over.  This happens automatically when you index using the `from docs.YourEntity` syntax in an index.  Raven does this behind the scenes when you use a dynamic index such as `.Query<YourEntity>` or `.Advanced.LuceneQuery<YourEntity>`.

Still, you shouldn't do this.

Comment: I already did all the normal RavenDB stuff in the rest of my application. Now I want an easy and quick way to look at my data directly from my web application as I am developing it and testing out new features.

Comment: Can you help me understand how I use `Raven-Entity-Type` in a text based LuceneQuery?

Comment: It all depends on what kind of web application you are writing.  For example, you might create a WebAPI controller and expose an `IQueryable` as an OData endpoint and consume it from jQuery.  Or you might just dump the results out to an ASP.Net page.  Perhaps you should ask a more specific question.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  The metadata value is called `Raven-Entity-Name`.  You need to index it first.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15387422/634824) that queries against the built-in `RavenDocumentsByEntityName` index.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Matt. I thought it was implied that the `session` I am using above is a RavenDb Session that I get like this from my C# code: `_documentStore.OpenSession()`. Then it's not relevant whether I am using jQuery or whatever, I just need to get the data out without stating the entity at compile time.

I'll try with the example from the answer you linked to. Thanks. It looks promising.

Comment: Hi again Matt. I tried the answer from the other question, but it doesn't seem to return anything. I put it in the question (it's more spacious up there) - can your sharp eyes see where I went wrong?

Comment: Try `LuceneQuery<object, RavenDocumentsByEntityName>`.  The index needs to be the second constraint

Comment: Thanks - it worked well. However, as I might have expected, it is not possible to add additional conditions to the query, as none other are included in that index. The only workaround I can think of is to `ToList()` it and work with the rest in memory. Would you say that's right?

Comment: Just create your own index.  That was just an example.